# remove blank lines at the beginning

Tags: php, regex

I try to remove blank lines

```
    <--- space or empty line 
lorem ipsum 
---empty line----
dolores
```

to this (with an empty line after ipsum)

```
lorem ipsum 
---empty line----
dolores
```

I make this function, it's work but can I do it better with regex ?

```
$lines=explode("\n", $content);
function clean($l){
  if(trim($l['0'])==''){
    array_shift($l);
    return clean($l);
  } 
    return $l;
 } 
$content=implode("\n",clean($lines));
```

Comment: What is in `$content`, is it a html file? If so, use `<br>` not `\n`

Comment: Just use trim function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear, but ltrim is what I'm searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should work better:

```
$content = ltrim($content);
```

Comment: great solution, I know trim() but ltrim() do the job for my problem !

Comment: Don't forget rtrim()! :D

Comment: @i-CONICA: "remove blank lines at the **beginning**"

Comment: @AbraCadaver I know. I was remarking on the comment made by the OP that he knew of trim(), but not ltrim(). I pointing out that there's also rtrim().